# Numerical Optimal Trajectory Generation using NLP

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, control-theory, nonlinear-system, optimal-control

I have been reading about direct collocation for trajectory generation and I am a bit confused - the examples I have seen result in having to maintain a separate nonlinear equality constraint for every sample point.

Is this normal?

How do numerical solvers maintain this many equality constraints in nonlinear programs?(I'm talking in the 100s). I have taken a course on nonlinear optimization using things like the projected gradient method but my understanding is that it is only viable for smaller scale problems. How is this normally handled?

Comment: Some information would be helpful, how many samples points are we talking about? What is the model?

Comment: @LinAlg Hi, I have seen examples with 100 points, example this:https://www.hindawi.com/journals/aaa/2014/851720/, equation 32 enforces continuity constraints on the sequence of state values. Basically it transforms the problem into a NLP problem with many equality constraints. In the article it wrote that variations of Newtons Method are used to solve it but it seems so massive to solve. The Projected Gradient Method isn't mentioned so I assume it's too large for that.

Comment: Also SQP is used(I guess it is the same as Newtons Method) but I'm confused why the actual problems constraint set isn't violated if you use these approximations. For example in the projected gradient method you actually project your answer back onto the constraint set which doesn't appear to be done here!

Comment: what's the point of adding a bounty if you don't show any interest in the answers?

Comment: did you appreciate any of the answers at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQP and interior point methods iterative approximate the optimization problem with an optimization problem with a quadratic objective and linear equality constraints:
$$\min \left\{ \frac{1}{2} x^TQx + c^Tx : Ax = b \right\}.$$
What is nice about this approximation is that the KKT conditions (necessary and sufficient if $Q$ is positive semidefinite) are just a linear system:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}Q & A^T \\ A & O\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ \lambda\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-c \\ b\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Therefore, the optimal solution to the approximation can be obtained by solving a system of linear equations. Just a few hundred variables is not a big deal. Especially when $A$ is sparse, you can solve such problems with millions of variables.

Comment: But how are all the constraints maintained? I guess you use Newtons Method applied to the SQP problem?

Comment: @FourierFlux The pair $(x,\lambda)$ that solves the KKT conditions satisfy $Ax=b$. Typically you add a line search step, so in the first iterations the constraints can be violated, but at some point the algorithm can take full or almost full steps and the iterates will satisfy satisfy $Ax=b$.

Answer (score 1):

As my background is mainly focused on MPC but not mathematical solvers, I only answer the first part of your question.

An example of NLP with many constraints is a Model Predictive Control (MPC) problem with a stability condition of

System Energy $|_{t=N_p T_s}$ = 0

This enforces every state of the system to be placed at a certain value. So, such equality conditions are normal.